# MKReverseGeoCoderDelegate not being called

Tags: iphone, mkreversegeocoder

I am trying to use the MKReverseGeoCoder API to get a city name based of a coordinate.  For some reason the delegate never gets called; any ideas why?  Here is the code:

```
- (void)startReverseLookup
{
  [reverseCoordinateInfo initWithCoordinate:self.currentlocation.coordinate];
  [reverseCoordinateInfo setDelegate:self];
  [reverseCoordinateInfo  start];
  NSLog(@"Reverse Geocode started");
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
     {
      NSLog(@"RC - ERROR !!!");
      }

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark    *)placemark
 {
     NSLog(@"RC lookup finished !! - Locality is:%@",placemark.locality);
 }
```

I am declaring the protocol on the .h file and then I call startReverseLookup. I see the first NSLog, but after that nothing happens—it just stays there forever and the delegate never gets called for either method. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following method -

```
- (void)startReverseLookup
{
    reverseCoordinateInfo = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.currentlocation.coordinate];
    [reverseCoordinateInfo setDelegate:self];
    [reverseCoordinateInfo  start];
    NSLog(@"Reverse Geocode started");
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked.   So i guess i forgot to do the object alloc.

Comment: thx a lot, will probably initiate it in the general class designated initializer